# how can i add message author id to AddFields value?

Tags: discord.js

How can i add the message author id to the value?

the code:

.addFields(
{ name: 'ID', value: "i want the user id here", inline: true }

```
        )
```

Comment: What's wrong with `{ name: 'ID', value: message.author.id, inline: true }`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
.addField(`ID:`, `${message.author.id}`, true);
```

Would be the correct method to approach it or as [Zslot Meszaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6126373/zsolt-meszaros) suggested you can try

```js
.addFields({ name: 'ID', value: message.author.id, inline: true });
```